# setCompoundDrawables with RemoteViews

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I have an appwidget layout with a textview and an imageview.

Lint always tells me to replace it with a compound textview.

The problem is, how do I call setCompoundDrawables with a RemoteViews?
is it possible?

thanks.

**UPDATE:** http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29249

Comment: I can't recollect how I did it or whether it is relevant, but once I'd annotated a method as "@Remotable" and was able to invoke it later. Not sure if it can help in this case. Otherwise, I don't see any other way it can be done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This option was added in API Level 16 (Android 4.1 Jellybean):

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setTextViewCompoundDrawables(int, int, int, int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setTextViewCompoundDrawables%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 1):

When you use setCompoundDrawables , you need code like :

```
Drawable img;
Resources res = getResources();
img = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_img);
//You need to setBounds before setCompoundDrawables , or it couldn't display
img.setBounds(0, 0, img.getMinimumWidth(), img.getMinimumHeight());
btn.setCompoundDrawables(img_off, null, null, null);
```

So you must have ways to call getResources()!
You can pass Activity context as a param to use getResources() & findViewById.

Comment: getResources is not the problem. RemoteViews doesn't have setCompoundDrawables method. My current answer is that it's not possible. maybe in jellybean..

Answer (score 0):

use setTextViewCompoundDrawables

```
contentiew.setTextViewCompoundDrawables(R.id.setting_btn, 0, R.mipmap.ic_gray_setting,0,0);
```